# What does "the lines of artist" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I stumpled upon this text but I did not understand what it means with:" the lines of the artist"

> The girl on my left enjoyed the lines of the artist standing at the corner.

Comment: Could you please give more context or a link to the source. It could mean different things depending on context.

Comment: @Peter unfortunately there is no more context,that's only what in my hand is

Comment: It's ambiguous, it could mean the **queue of admirers**, it could mean the **body shape of the artist**, it could mean the **artistic lines in the artwork by the artist**, it could mean any one of those off the top of my head. The only thing not ambiguous is **the girl on your left** and **the artist at the corner** (of the street?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is ambiguous and cannot be answered without additional information.

Comment: *At* should be *in*, unless the artist is *close* to the corner, then we can use *by*. The structure of the question is great for ELL.

Answer (score 4):

This sentence is a little confusing because it is complex.  If we split it up into ideas, it becomes clearer:

There was a girl on my left.

She enjoyed the lines.

The lines belonged to the artist who was standing on the corner.

This is confusing because "lines" could mean several things.  We know it is related to an artist, so it could be lines that the artist is drawing, but it would be a strange way to describe a drawing. "Lines" is not a normal way to describe visual art, and suggests the art is not finished, but the artist is described as standing and not drawing.

Alternately, the artist could be reciting lines of poetry.  This is less strained grammatically, but we would expect a poetry performance to be described.

"Lines" can also refer to a profile, as if the artist were attractive and the girl was enjoying that.

Without more context, it is hard to judge the author's intent.

Comment: I thought maybe native speakers use this phrase, I didn't know it was ambiguous,because I'm not a native speaker thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

This must be a reference to *Line Art*.

> **Line Art**
>     Usually single-color drawing (such as one made with a pen or pencil) with little or no solid areas, and no shading effect
>   other than cross-hatching. Line art, unlike a painting or photograph,
>   can be printed without conversion to a halftone image. Also called
>   line copy or line drawing.

The Artist, presently standing in the corner, creates works of art displaying a solid grasp of depth, contour and shape - in the opinion of the girl on your left.

One imagines each line is as thick, thin or varied as the image being rendered requires, so as to leave no room for doubt about the nature of the drawing.

A possible parallel would be a painting that did not display *visible* brush strokes.